# Oozie File Based Coordinator for Dynamic Date Bases Filename

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, oozie, oozie-coordinator

We receive files in the format data_YYYYMMDD.avro e.g. data_20160927.avro into a dynamically named folder in the format schemaNNN e.g. schema003

Is it possible to set up a coordinator that will trigger a workflow when a file containing the previous days date arrives?

I've tried using a dataset but have encountered the following issues:

1. The uri-template does not seem to allow wildcards e.g. /parentFolder/schema*
2. The done-flag does not seem to allow EL functions e.g. data_${YEAR}${MONTH}${DAY}.avro

Comment: `schemaDDD` why 3 D's here? can it be two to match with `DD`?

Comment: The DDD was to represent digits e.g. 001, 002, 204 etc. but I see how it can be confused with days

Comment: @Breandán does it means that for each day the schemaNNN folder will change ?

Comment: It _may_ do but not a given